# Select a node in jstree using regular expression in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jstree, selectnodes

I am testing my UI behavior and I am trying to click on a jstree node programmatically:

```
    $('#search_jstree_id')
        .jstree(true)
        .select_node('nodeName');
```

But the `nodeName` comes from users search and it is not exact match with the existing nodes, so I want to use a regular expression in `.select_node`. I can not make it work. Is it possible? Any other way for jstree?

Comment: I think you can use a selector, like: `.select_code('.jstree-node[id*="' + selector + '"]')`, where selector is the user input.

Comment: I know nothing about jsTree, but looking at the documentation, it looks like the [search plugin](https://www.jstree.com/api/#/?f=search\() might be what you're looking for...

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ $("#search_tree").click(function () {    

var value=document.getElementById("search_field").value;

  $("#search_jstree_id'").jstree("search",value);

  });  //here search_tree is a id of a button and call with click ebvent

Comment: answer by @trincot worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a regular expression, but you can use a CSS selector, like:

```
.select_code('.jstree-node[id*="' + selector + '"]')
```

...where `selector` is the user input. It will match nodes which have an `id` that contains the provided string. So for example if `selector = 'can'` then it could match nodes `candle` and `scanned`, but not `clan`.